# 後で vs. 前に. Why not the same particle?

Tags: particles, time, に-and-で

Why don't 後で and 前に both use the same particle? (I suppose I would think に would be more appropriate.) They both seem to be the same kind of statement, just with different times (before/after), so I really can't think of any reason for the particle discrepancy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Cross-linguistically, grammatical words like に and で are often unpredictable or idiosyncratic, and you can't always explain them logically.

For example, in English, we say *arrive at* but not **arrive to*.  And we say *Welcome to X* but not **Welcome at X*.  Why?  [No reason.  It's arbitrary.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=7476)  It seems like the alternatives should be just as logical, but for some reason we only say them a certain way.  And sometimes these requirements vary over time, or from place to place.  For example, American English speakers say *on the weekend*, but British speakers say [*at the weekend*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/75488)  Unfortunately, language learners have to memorize these facts and move on.

#### So what about 前に and あとで?

Here's what Samuel Martin writes in *A Reference Grammar of Japanese* (1975), p.219, as part of his multi-page explanation of に versus で:

> Unexplained is the following anomaly: 前に 'before' refers to order (= 先に), time, or static space, and 前で '(happening) in front' refers only to space; あとに 'after' refers only to order and あとで 'after' only to time (with 後ろに／で 'behind' designating space).  Some sort of semantic cancellation may be present; or perhaps the overlap with the copula infinitive and gerund has confused the picture.

So the reason is unclear, at least to Martin.  We can still try to guess, though!  Etymologically で is a contraction of にて (and you can still hear にて occasionally in very formal registers), so perhaps we might speculate that the difference is related to て suggesting temporal order ("after").

But I personally think you're better off just memorizing 前に and あとで and not trying to find the logic behind them—it's possible there's no logic to find!