# I don't get how 今日 works in 今日は誘ってくれて嬉しかった.

Tags: grammar, usage

I was watching Sora no Method 06, and at about 17:03 the line 今日は誘ってくれて嬉しかった came up. Crunchyroll translated the line as "I'm happy you invited me today," but the problem is that she was invited the day before, not today, but Crunchyroll's line made it seem like she was invited today. Is it possible that 今日 only modifies 嬉しかった and doesn't necessarily specify the day that 誘う happened?

Comment: Insert a mental "for" in "invited me _for_ today". It's about the day something is happening, not the day that the invitation was made.

Comment: Wouldn't you usually use に when you're using 誘う like that instead of は?

Comment: は doesn't behave nicely. It can override に if you topicalize whatever it was attached to, just as it can override を. However, that's not the only way to interpret this sentence. You're absolutely right that it could apply only to 嬉しかった, as "Today, I was happy you invited me."

Comment: Clarification: "can override" in this case means two different things for に and を: を is always replaced outside of poetry or certain other rare contexts, but both は and には are found. Here is some futher discussion: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17571/what-is-the-subject-of-this-sentence-is-it-the-book-mentioned-or-the-author/17574#17574 and the source mentioned in that post: http://usf.usfca.edu/japanese/Topicalization.pdf

Comment: @Joe: 今日 usually doesn't take に while 日曜日 or １５日 do.

Comment: Well, what I meant is that you usually use に for 誘う, and it doesn't really have anything to do with whether it's 今日 or not. Like, for 私は彼女をデートに誘った you have to use に to specify the event you're inviting the person to, but I still don't really get whether you can drop the に.

Answer (score 6):

今日は誘ってくれて嬉しかった sounds perfectly natural to me. I think it's like "Thank you for asking me out for today." implying "Today, I had a great time."

今日誘ってくれて嬉しかった sounds to me like "I was happy you asked me out TODAY, not another day."

Answer (score 1):

That 今日 indicates the day when she felt happy. If it's the day when she was invited (for), the sentence would be 今日誘ってくれて嬉しかった.