# と quotation particle: Omission and the で particle

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-で, anime, quotes

I have two questions about the と quotation particle. One about it's omission together with connected verbs and the other about how it operates with the で particle. I believe the bellow sentence contains an omission of と思う:

> Original: 世間では警察も無能、Lも無能.
>
> My extension: 世間では警察も無能、Lも無能と思う

The translation I have reads

> "People think [society thinks] L and the police are incompetent".

I don't see how I could've gotten that from the original. The only thing I can think of is that と思う is being omitted, because I don't see how the sentence makes sense otherwise.

In addition, I'd like to know how exactly the で particle operate with the と particle here, because I don't quite understand it.

If someone could clear this up that would be great :). Thanks!

> [The context is that these are police officers and the superior is
> talking about how "L" who is a character and the police are
> incompetent. The example is from episode 10 of Death Note.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The omitted verb is a bit different from what you have in mind:

> 世間では警察も無能、Lも無能**と思われている**。
>   In the society, it is thought that both the police and L are incompetent.

Note that I used the passive form here. The sentence is not saying "society thinks ～" with the society as the subject. で here is a simple location marker, "*in* the society" (or "in the public mind").

If it were not for で, 世間 would work as the subject, so 思っている (non-passive) would be the right omitted verb:

> 世間は警察も無能、Lも無能**と思っている**。
>   The society thinks that both the police and L are incompetent.

Comment: ahhhh that makes so much sense now. 本当にありがとう！

Comment: However, can you explain the difference between が and で in this context of using the passive?

Comment: Also how does は work together with で here, given that the original sentence has both?

Comment: @DelectableTea The two sentences are almost identical in meaning. は is the *topic marker* and can attach to various other particles. See [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17574/5010).

Comment: Ah so it's just a difference of inference, thar is, figuring out the omitted verb is passive?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't understand much of that post, as it seemed to be discussing different particles than are used here.

Comment: @DelectableTea 世間では is just "In this society", with [は used as the topic marker](http://japanese.about.com/od/japanesevocabulary/fl/Japanese-Particles-Wa-VS-Ga.htm). The fact that は can attach to many particles is the key point. I used the passive form because it would be the shortest, but you may think the original sentence is short for 世間では人々が警察も無能、Lも無能と思っている。

Comment: Ah I think I finally get it. It's not that で is being used versus any other particle (such as は) is being used with the passive form, but that that is the shortest way to make the sentence "complete" for my understanding. Thus, the passive works if one wanted, as you did originally, to add as little to the sentence as possible, as it works with the で particle. Many thanks for your detailed engagement with my question! ありがとうございました