# Why wa in Karaoke wa suki desu ka?

Tags: particle-は, questions, は-and-が

I recently came across an example in a text book

```
 カラオケは好きですか。
```

and was not sure why `wa` was used here instead of `ga`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > カラオケは好きですか。
>
> why wa was used here instead of ga?

は is good for talking about *general idea*, and this is the one to present the subject/theme of the sentence.
が usually introduces a happening, or is good at indicating the subject/theme of *modifying clauses*.

In Japanese, the action maker is often omitted (because often the verb, or the context, tells who or what is the action maker), but one of the basic sentence structures is

**～は、～が～です。**

田中さんは、カラオケ**は**お好きですか。[a question about a general preference / we could have plural subjects/themes (田中さんは and カラオケは)]

あ、田中さんはカラオケ**が**お好きなんですね。[a remark after finding out the fact]

はい、カラオケは好きです。[a statement about a general preference]

はい、そうなんです。カラオケが好きなんです。[could sound like after having a trouble mixed up as though something else is your preference]

はい、そうなんです。カラオケは好きなんです。[after having a trouble mixed up as though you don't like karaoke]

Answer (score 3):

は is a topic maker, and it can *replace* some particles including が. Here, カラオケ is the main topic of the sentence, and that's why it's marked with は instead of が. See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17574/5010) for details.

カラオケ would be marked with が in the following two types of situations:

1. When there is a different topic in the main clause:

   > 彼**は**カラオケ**が**好きですか。  (Here 彼 is the topic)
   >   Does he like *karaoke*?
2. When this part is inside a [relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) (because a relative clause is just a modifier and does not serve as the topic of the whole sentence):

   > カラオケ**が**好きな人**は**多い。
   >   There are many people who like *karaoke*.