# へようこそ and にようこそ

Tags: word-choice

I've noticed that both へ and に are use with ようこそ.  The one I learned first is へ, and it seems like it's more common, but I know に is also used, as in the title [NHKにようこそ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHK%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D!).

When I search [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/), I find that へ is more common, at least when it comes right before ようこそ:

```
　へようこそ　　　69 results
　にようこそ　　　37 results
```

Of course, this is a written corpus and it might be different in speech.  But assuming I'm right that へ is generally more common, are there any other differences between the two?  I always say へ, but every time I hear に I wonder if there's a difference in register or such that I'm not picking up on, or if they're totally the same.

Comment: I think へ is preferred in titles, slogans, and when the verb is omitted. http://nhg.pro.tok2.com/qa/joshi-14.htm

Comment: ^ 確かにプレゼントとか宛名などには「～さん**へ** 」ですね・・　でも『アルジャーノン**に**花束を』『まごころを、君**に** 。』とかもありますよね・・

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no difference in politeness, register, gender, etc., between the two.

"Welcome to X" on the welcome signs for tourists is more commonly written as "ようこそX**へ**". This is a well-known idiom; if I saw "ようこそ日本**に**" at Narita Airport, I would feel it's a bit unnatural.

However, I feel 「Xへようこそ」 and 「Xにようこそ」 are *completely* interchangeable, when X is 私の家, 東京, 日本, NHK, グーグル, グランドキャニオン or even 宇宙.

(By the way, this is a topic I've been concerned about, too, since I saw an [OP's answer in a different question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/).)