# The particle に when used with 移動する

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, particles

部屋{へや}へ移動{いどう}します。= Move to the room.

部屋から移動します。= Move from the room.

But if I use に, does the sentence「部屋に移動します。」mean to "move to the room" or "move from the room"? Or can the meaning be either depending on context, as with a lot of other cases using に? I'm not sure whether the verb 移動する itself already implies the direction of the movement. Since it also means "removal", I thought it must always mean "move from" but I'm not sure.

If it can be either, is there any difference in meaning/nuance between using に or へ to mean "to"　and に or から to mean "from", particularly in relation to the verb 移動する?

Comment: I know the に・へ comparison has been asked on this site before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

に and へ are interchangeable at least in your example. See the following questions for details.

- [Is へ and に interchangeable in these cases?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26015/5010)
- [Can't に always replace へ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2166/5010)
- [へようこそ and にようこそ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18268/5010)

To be clear, 部屋に移動します is the same as 部屋へ移動します (move *to* the room).

移動 on its own just means "move", not "remove".