# use of に or で for 寄ってください as a location particle

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

As far as I can understand about location に indicates a location where something exists  (as in ここに いる), but some verbs use it like つとめる
 and で the location on which an action takes place ( as in レストランで食事をする or 待つ) but with  寄る に is used (according to the N4 preparatory book), I don't understand why, may I ask your help with this?

Comment: `に indicates a location where something exists (as in ここに いる)` >> But you'd also use に for "to (direction/destination)" as in "日本**に**行く(go to Japan)", right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As for 待つ, it's always used with で. I don't know when to use に.
- As for 寄る, に is used in the same way as ～に行く ("go to ～"), ～に来る ("come to ～"), ～に向かう ("head to ～"), ～に送る ("send (something) to ～"), etc. It's the primary particle that marks a destination.

That said, you cannot always expect a logical answer for this kind of question. You may find this interesting:

[後で　vs. 前に- Why not the same particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16269/5010)

---

(By the way, whenever I see "to drop *by* ～", I can't help feeling it's counter-intuitive...)

Comment: thank you! so it is because so, I guess it is the same with 時間に遅れる

Comment: `(By the way, whenever I see "to drop by ～", I can't help feeling it's counter-intuitive...)`  Why?  Counter-intuitive to what?  Just curious...

Comment: @istrasci My intuition as a native Japanese says "to drop to ～" or "to drop at ～" is somehow more reasonable :-) Well, never mind please.