# Why is に used here and are there any possible replacements for it here?

Tags: syntax, particle-に

> 彼は生徒に人気がある

I have done a quick search and I have found in cases where 人気のある and 人気がある are used that に marks who something is popular with most of the time. Why is に used here and could we use some alternative to mark 生徒?

Comment: I wonder how you explain why it's marked by "with" in English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [almost impossible to explain why](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16270/5010) when it comes to particle choice. I don't know why English speakers say "be popular with ～", but not "be popular to ～", but perhaps that's something you have to memorize rather than wondering why. It's the sixth (or eighth?) definition of [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB/), if it helps. English is equally "illogical"; also see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42912/8629).

So you should memorize ～は～に人気がある / ～は～に人気だ as a set phrase. You may see の used instead of が in a relative clause ([that's a universal grammatical rule](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)).

Using と will not make sense at all. Occasionally へ is used in a relative clause, but I would say using に is always the safest.

> - 生徒に人気がある先生 a teacher who is popular with students
> - 生徒へ人気がある先生 (less common)
> - [x] 生徒と人気がある先生 (plain wrong)

Answer (score 0):

It basically means "He is popular with the students. set expression "に人気がある"