# Usage of で particle in this sentence: この問題用紙は全部で8ページあります

Tags: particles, particle-が, particle-で

Usage of particle で and に have been causing me quite some difficulties from the beginning (I keep on using で instead of に and vice versa). From what I've learned so far, particle で indicates either where an action is taking place or by what means.

So how come で is being used with...全部... to mean "in all there is.."?

I would rather write it at as :

- この問題用紙は**全部**、8ページ**が**あります。 or,
- この問題用紙は**全部に**8ページがあります。*(Maybe I'm interpreting に particle too literally here)*

Also, is the usage of particle が optional when stating 'there is something', so using あります? This was the first example I've seen that didn't use particle が with あります。 *(As some might have recognized, this example is from a JLPT test, so there isn't a possibility it was just omitted)*

I would appreciate it if someone can translate what my versions of the sentences would mean *(この問題用紙は全部、8ページがあります。and この問題用紙は全部に8ページがあります。)*, so I'd be able to compare them and maybe understand better. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「この問題用紙{もんだいようし}は全部{ぜんぶ}**で**8ページあります。」

The 「で」 here is used to describe what the ***standard (or limitation)*** is for the object being talked about.  In Japanese, the shorter the words, the more meanings they have.  「で」 is no exception and I recommend that you look it up in a **monolingual** dictionary in the near future.

In the meantime, however, it would also be important that you learn that 「全部で」, as a phrase, means "***in total***".

**In the sentence in question, no other word can replace the 「で」**.  Particles are far more stubborn and inflexible than Japanese-learners wish that they were.

> "The question sheets consist of 8 pages in total."

is what the sentence means.

Your sentences:

1) この問題用紙は全部、8ページ**が**あります。

2) この問題用紙は全部**に**8ページ**が**あります。

I am afraid that neither sentence makes much sense.  As an owner of a Japanese-speaking mind, I have no idea why you are using a 「が」.

Upon hearing/seeing 「8ページ**が**」, most Japanese-speakers would think, as I would, that you were talking about "***page 8***" of a book of some kind -- as in "Page 8 is very interesting.".  In describing the quantity/volume, 「8ページ**が**」 sounds very "off".  Thus, it is not a question of the 「が」 being optional or not; It is simply incorrect to use it.

For this reason, both of your sentences do not really mean anything.  But they ***could*** be taken to mean the **strangest** thing.

Both "could" be taken to mean:

> "All these sets of question sheets contain page 8."

which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

で has multiple meanings. Unit or standard for calculation is one ([6] in this page: https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%81%A7).

As for problems of your examples, first, ８ページ is, usually and in this case too, an adverb. So, saying ８ページが is as unnatural, I believe, as "Today is rain" instead of "It's rain today".

Second, に combined with verb ある stands for a location where the contents of the clause（８ページある） takes place. In short, この問題用紙は全部に８ページある means that all the sets of the exam papers (of a specific type, which singular この stands for) consist of 8 pages each.

Comment: `as unnatural... as "Today is rain" instead of "It's rain today"` -- It's rain today も自然ではないですよね。。。

Comment: "It's rainy" だったっけ？

Answer (score 1):

This で is explained as "a condition/situation marker".

> - テニスで彼女に勝った。
> - 寝不足で仕事に行った。
> - 往復で2万円かかった。

全部 without で would mean "all/everything" rather than "*in* all". Anyway, basically 全部で is a set phrase you should learn by rote. [Basic function words like で/に/in/with are often unpredictable](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16270/5010), after all.

You *should not* insert が after 8ページ. Japanese numbers work adverbially, e.g., リンゴが5個あります, 本を3冊買いました, ビールを2杯ください.